# DIsplaying URL of custom field in last post of certain taxonomy && post type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field

So, I need to echo the URL of a custom field from the **last post published** in a certain post type and with a particular taxonomy.

This code so far works OK, but even that `numberposts = 1`,  `$imagecurrent` will contain the image URL **from all the posts** matching the conditions, **not only the last one**.

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'=> 1,
        'post_type'     => 'exhibition',
        'tax_query' => array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'exhibitions',
          'field' => 'id',
          'terms' => 720, // Where term_id of Term 1 is "1".
        )),
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>
<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
    <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php echo $imagecurrent = get_field('exhibition_menu_image');
    ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

I have included the code from the solution (posts_per_page), but it's still spitting out the URL from all posts, not only the last one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`numberposts` doesn't exist for [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) instead use

`"posts_per_page" => 1`

Comment: Still spitting more than one URL! : /

Comment: That's true but note `numberposts` works for `get_posts()` and other wrapper functions.

Comment: Can you update the code with latest one ? @EricMitjans

Comment: @Sumit Done, but still not working.

Comment: Then issue might be `get_field()` function. Try displaying post ID using `the_ID()` instead of `get_field()` and share how many IDs do you see ?

Comment: @Sumit I get as many IDs as posts exist in this particular taxonomy, so basically, same problem : )

Comment: Well that's weird because there is nothing wrong with the code may be theme plugins causing this issue. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41710/discussion-between-eric-mitjans-and-sumit).